# css code not working in container elementor

Tags: css, text, containers, elementor, lightening

My custom css code in elementor container is not working.

can you please take a look at it? I already tried so many methods, but it still has problems.

```
:root{
    --dark: #0D1C45;
    --white: #ffffff;
    --glow: #03bcf4;
}

selector h2 {
    animation:animate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%,18%,20%,50.1%,60%,65.1%,80%,90.1%,92%{
        color: var(--dark);
        text-shadow: none;
    }
    18.1%,20.1%,30%,50%,60.1%,65%,80.1%,90%,92.1%,100%{
        color: var(--white);
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--glow),
         0 0 20px var(--glow),
          0 0 40px var(--glow),
           0 0 80px var(--glow),
           0 0 160px var(--glow);
    }
}
```

Comment: The various tickmarks and bits of text make this code syntactically invalid in the first place.  Can you update this to include a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what problem you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is `selector h2 {}`. "selector" is not a valid [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors). The animation works after deleting "selector".

```css
:root{
    --dark: #0D1C45;
    --white: #ffffff;
    --glow: #03bcf4;
}

h2 {
    animation:animate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%,18%,20%,50.1%,60%,65.1%,80%,90.1%,92%{
        color: var(--dark);
        text-shadow: none;
    }
    18.1%,20.1%,30%,50%,60.1%,65%,80.1%,90%,92.1%,100%{
        color: var(--white);
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--glow),
         0 0 20px var(--glow),
          0 0 40px var(--glow),
           0 0 80px var(--glow),
           0 0 160px var(--glow);
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>animation:animate</h2>
```